# Return Row Header Info on a < Condition in Matrix Lookup

Tags: excel

I have a table comprised of breakeven points expressed as % utilization rates which are broken out by term and commitment level.

I'm looking to query that table and return the row header associated w/ the first value in the column which is lower than my comparison value.

I will always know what the term is as for these queries.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

***Matrix and Output Sample.***
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways to achieve this. You may try-

```
=XLOOKUP(C11,INDEX(B2:D6,,MATCH(C10,B7:D7,0)),A2:A6,"N/A",-1)
```

- Here `INDEX(B2:D6,,MATCH(C10,B7:D7,0))` will return the column by matching **Term**.
- Then `XLOOKUP()` will search for `Utilization` and return values from most left column of corresponding row of utilization by searching value or next lower value.

Another way could be.

```
=@SORT(FILTER(A2:D6,FILTER(B2:D6,B7:D7=C10)<=C12),MATCH(C10,B7:D7,0),-1)
```

[image]